# app resets after restarting

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I am trying to develop a simple app that when I buy an activity it makes the button enabled.

My code works fine but the problem is when I exit the app and reopen it, the buttons that was previously enabled after the purchase they become disabled however it doesn't allow to repurchase again.

(I need to do it on time purchase)

So how to keep the enabled buttons stays enabled when I restart the app?

Here is my code:

```
public class MainScreen extends ActionBarActivity {

private static final String TAG = "com.aseng90_test.smiap2";
IabHelper mHelper;
static final String ITEM_SKU = "com.aseng90_test.smiap2_button5";
static final String ITEM_SKU2 = "com.aseng90_test.smiap2_buyact2";
static final String ITEM_SKU3 = "com.aseng90_test.smiap2_buyact3";
static final String ITEM_SKU4 = "com.aseng90_test.smiap2_buyall";

public Button Activity1;
public Button Activity2;
public Button Activity3;


public Button buyButton;
public Button buyAct2;
public Button buyAct3;
public Button buyAll;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_screen);

    buyButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buyButton);
    buyAct2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buyact2);
    buyAct3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buyact3);
    buyAll = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buyall);


    Activity1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.act1);
    Activity2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.act2);
    Activity3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.act3);

    Activity1.setEnabled(false);
    Activity2.setEnabled(false);
    Activity3.setEnabled(false);

String base64EncodedPublicKey =
            "";

    mHelper = new IabHelper(this, base64EncodedPublicKey);

    mHelper.startSetup(new
                               IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
                                   public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result)
                                   {
                                       if (!result.isSuccess()) {
                                           Log.d(TAG, "In-app Billing setup failed: " +
                                                   result);
                                       } else {
                                           Log.d(TAG, "In-app Billing is set up OK");
                                       }
                                   }
                               });
}

public void buyClick(View view) {
    mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(this, ITEM_SKU, 10001,
            mPurchaseFinishedListener, "mypurchasetoken");
}

public void  buyAct2 (View view){
    mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(this, ITEM_SKU2, 10002, mPurchaseFinishedListener, "buyact2");
}

public void buyAct3 (View view){
    mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(this,ITEM_SKU3, 10003, mPurchaseFinishedListener, "buyact3");
}

public void buyAll (View view){
    mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(this, ITEM_SKU4,10004, mPurchaseFinishedListener, "buyall");
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                Intent data)
{
    if (!mHelper.handleActivityResult(requestCode,
            resultCode, data)) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}



IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener mPurchaseFinishedListener
        = new IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener() {
    public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result,
                                      Purchase purchase)
    {
        if (result.isFailure()) {
            // Handle error
            return;
        }
         if (purchase.getSku().equals(ITEM_SKU)) {
            Activity1.setEnabled(true);
            buyButton.setEnabled(false);
        }

         if (purchase.getSku().equals(ITEM_SKU2)){
        Activity2.setEnabled(true);
        buyAct2.setEnabled(false);
    }

       if (purchase.getSku().equals(ITEM_SKU3)){
            Activity3.setEnabled(true);
            buyAct3.setEnabled(false);
        }

      if (purchase.getSku().equals(ITEM_SKU4)) {
            Activity1.setEnabled(true);
            Activity2.setEnabled(true);
            Activity3.setEnabled(true);

            buyAll.setEnabled(false);
            buyButton.setEnabled(false);
            buyAct2.setEnabled(false);
            buyAct3.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }


};

public void Activity1 (View view)
{
    startActivity(new Intent(MainScreen.this, Click1.class));

}

public void Activity2 (View view){
    startActivity(new Intent(MainScreen.this, Activity2.class));
}

public void Activity3 (View view){
    startActivity(new Intent(MainScreen.this, Activity3.class));
}










@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mHelper != null ) mHelper.dispose();
    mHelper = null  ;
}
```

Thanks a lot

Ok so I used shared preference to save my activity state but it only works fine when I try to enable a button with another free button, but it doesn't work with the in app purchase button (simply it let me do the purchase but the deactivated button never turns enabled after the purchase) So I don't know if there is a conflict between in app purchase and shared preference in my code?

Here is my edited code:

> package com.aseng90_test.smiap2;
>
> import android.content.Intent; import
>   android.content.SharedPreferences; import
>   android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity; import android.os.Bundle;
>   import android.util.Log; import android.view.View; import
>   android.widget.Button; import android.widget.Toast;
>
> import com.aseng90_test.smiap2.util.IabHelper; import
>   com.aseng90_test.smiap2.util.IabResult; import
>   com.aseng90_test.smiap2.util.Purchase;
>
> public class MainScreen extends ActionBarActivity {
>
> ```
> private static final String TAG = "com.aseng90_test.smiap2";
> IabHelper mHelper;
> static final String ITEM_SKU = "com.aseng90_test.smiap2_button55";
> static final String ITEM_SKU2 = "com.aseng90_test.smiap2_buyact22";
> static final String ITEM_SKU3 = "com.aseng90_test.smiap2_buyact33";
> static final String ITEM_SKU4 = "com.aseng90_test.smiap2_buyall_1";
>
>
>
>
>
>
> private Button Activity1;
> private Button Activity2;
> private Button Activity3;
>
> private Button buyButton;
> private Button buyAct2;
> private Button buyAct3;
> private Button buyAll;
> ```
>
> private Button EAct4;    private Button Act4;
>
> ```
> private SharedPreferences prefs;
> private String prefName = "MyPref";
>
>
>  boolean Activity1_isEnabled;
>  boolean Activity2_isEnabled;
>  boolean Activity3_isEnabled;
>  boolean Act4_isEnabled;
>
>  boolean buyButton_isEnabled;
>  boolean buyAct2_isEnabled;
>  boolean buyAct3_isEnabled;
>  boolean buyAll_isEnabled;
>  boolean EAct4_isEnabled;
>
> private static final String Activity1_state = "Activity1_state";
> private static final String Activity2_State = "Activity2_state";
> private static final String Activity3_State = "Activity3_state";
> private static final String buyButton_State = "buyButton_state";
> private static final String buyAct2_State = "buyAct2_state";
> private static final String buyAct3_State = "buyAct3_state";
> private static final String buyAll_State = "buyAll_state";
> private static final String Act4_State = "Act4_state";
> private static final String EAct4_State = "EAct4_state";
>
>
>
> public void buyClick(View view) {
>     mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(this, ITEM_SKU, 10001,
>             mPurchaseFinishedListener, "mypurchasetoken");
> }
>
> public void  buyAct2 (View view){
>     mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(this, ITEM_SKU2, 10002, mPurchaseFinishedListener, "buyact2");
> }
>
> public void buyAct3 (View view){
>     mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(this,ITEM_SKU3, 10003, mPurchaseFinishedListener, "buyact3");
> }
>
> public void buyAll (View view){
>     mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(this, ITEM_SKU4,10004, mPurchaseFinishedListener, "buyall");
> }
>
>
> @Override
> protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_screen);
>
>     buyButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buyButton);
>     buyAct2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buyact2);
>     buyAct3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buyact3);
>     buyAll = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buyall);
>
>
>     Activity1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.act1);
>     Activity2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.act2);
>     Activity3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.act3);
>
>
>
>
>     EAct4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.eact4);
>     Act4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.act4);
>
>
>
>
>
>     String base64EncodedPublicKey =
>             "";
>
>     mHelper = new IabHelper(this, base64EncodedPublicKey);
>
>     mHelper.startSetup(new
>           IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
>            public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result)
>          {
>             if (!result.isSuccess()) {
>              Log.d(TAG, "In-app Billing setup failed: " + result);
>               } else {
>                  Log.d(TAG, "In-app Billing is set up OK");
>                   }
>          }
>      });
> }
>
>
>
>
>
> public void EACT4 (View view) {
>     EAct4.setEnabled(false);
>     Act4.setEnabled(true);
>
>
> }
>
> public void ACT4 (View view){
>     Toast.makeText(MainScreen.this,
>             "ACt4 Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
> }
>
> @Override
> protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
>                                 Intent data)
> {
>     if (!mHelper.handleActivityResult(requestCode,
>             resultCode, data)) {
>         super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
>     }
> }
>
>
>
> IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener mPurchaseFinishedListener
>         = new IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener() {
>     public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result,
>                                       Purchase purchase)
>     {
>         if (result.isFailure()) {
>             // Handle error
>             return;
>         }
>          if (purchase.getSku().equals(ITEM_SKU)) {
>             Activity1.setEnabled(true);
>             buyButton.setEnabled(false);
>
>         }
>
>          if (purchase.getSku().equals(ITEM_SKU2)){
>         Activity2.setEnabled(true);
>         buyAct2.setEnabled(false);
>     }
>
>        if (purchase.getSku().equals(ITEM_SKU3)){
>             Activity3.setEnabled(true);
>             buyAct3.setEnabled(false);
>         }
>
>       if (purchase.getSku().equals(ITEM_SKU4)) {
>             Activity1.setEnabled(true);
>             Activity2.setEnabled(true);
>             Activity3.setEnabled(true);
>
>             buyAll.setEnabled(false);
>             buyButton.setEnabled(false);
>             buyAct2.setEnabled(false);
>             buyAct3.setEnabled(false);
>         }
>     }
>
>
> };
>
>
>
>
> public void Activity1 (View view)
> {
>     startActivity(new Intent(MainScreen.this, Click1.class));
>
> }
>
> public void Activity2 (View view){
>     startActivity(new Intent(MainScreen.this, Activity2.class));
> }
>
> public void Activity3 (View view){
>     startActivity(new Intent(MainScreen.this, Activity3.class));
> }
>
>
> @Override
> public void onDestroy() {
>     super.onDestroy();
>     if (mHelper != null ) mHelper.dispose();
>     mHelper = null  ;
> }
>
>
> @Override
> protected void onPause(){
>     super.onPause();
>
>     if (Act4.isEnabled()){
>         Act4_isEnabled = true;
>     }
>     else {
>         Act4_isEnabled = false;
>     }
>
>
>     if (Activity1.isEnabled()){
>         Activity1_isEnabled = true;
>     }
>     else {
>         Activity1_isEnabled = false;
>     }
>
>     if (Activity2.isEnabled()){
>         Activity2_isEnabled = true;
>     }
>     else {
>         Activity2_isEnabled = false;
>     }
>
>     if (Activity3.isEnabled()){
>         Activity3_isEnabled = true;
>     }
>     else {
>         Activity3_isEnabled = false;
>     }
>
>     if (buyButton.isEnabled()){
>         buyButton_isEnabled = true;
>     }
>     else {
>         buyButton_isEnabled = false;
>     }
>
>     if (buyAct2.isEnabled()){
>         buyAct2_isEnabled = true;
>     }
>     else {
>         buyAct2_isEnabled = false;
>     }
>
>     if (buyAct3.isEnabled()){
>         buyAct3_isEnabled = true;
>     }
>     else {
>         buyAct3_isEnabled = false;
>     }
>
>     if (buyAll.isEnabled()){
>         buyAll_isEnabled = true;
>     }
>     else {
>         buyAll_isEnabled = false;
>     }
>
>
>
>     prefs = getSharedPreferences(prefName,MODE_PRIVATE);
>     SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
>     editor.putBoolean(Act4_State,Act4_isEnabled);
>     editor.putBoolean(EAct4_State,EAct4_isEnabled);
>     editor.putBoolean(Activity1_state,Activity1_isEnabled);
>     editor.putBoolean(Activity2_State,Activity2_isEnabled);
>     editor.putBoolean(Activity3_State,Activity3_isEnabled);
>     editor.putBoolean(buyButton_State,buyButton_isEnabled);
>     editor.putBoolean(buyAct2_State,buyAct2_isEnabled);
>     editor.putBoolean(buyAct3_State,buyAct3_isEnabled);
>     editor.putBoolean(buyAll_State,buyAll_isEnabled);
>     editor.apply();
>
> }
>
> @Override
> protected void onResume(){
>     super.onResume();
>
>     prefs = getSharedPreferences(prefName,MODE_PRIVATE);
>
>     Act4.setEnabled(prefs.getBoolean(Act4_State,false));
>     Activity1.setEnabled(prefs.getBoolean(Activity1_state,false));
>     Activity2.setEnabled(prefs.getBoolean(Activity2_State,false));
>     Activity3.setEnabled(prefs.getBoolean(Activity3_State,false));
>
>     EAct4.setEnabled(prefs.getBoolean(EAct4_State,true));
>     buyButton.setEnabled(prefs.getBoolean(buyButton_State,true));
>     buyAct2.setEnabled(prefs.getBoolean(buyAct2_State,true));
>     buyAct3.setEnabled(prefs.getBoolean(buyAct3_State,true));
>     buyAll.setEnabled(prefs.getBoolean(buyAll_State,true));
> }
> ```

Thanks again

Comment: Why don't you store those values in DB?

Comment: How to do that? @VVB

Comment: Store the values which keep track of purchase.

Answer (score 0):

When your activity is restarted, it does not save the state of its views from the previous instance. Thus you probably need to save your state data somewhere so that when you restart your activity, you can then reset your views looking at this saved state data.You can make use of "SharedPreferences" class. SharedPreferences lets you store information in key-value pair. I guess that serves your purpose.

```
    SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("ProductCache", 0); 
// 0 - for private mode
//First parameter is the name of your preference file.Could be "ProductCache" in your case.
// Default 0 for private access.
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit(); // edit your preference file
editor.putString("KEY","VALUE");//save strings
editor.putBoolean("KEY",true);//save booleans or any other type of data.
editor.commit(); //commit your changes
```

You can set that your product is already bought in your mPurchaseFinishedListener.Next time your app is opened you can check the same file by using the same "keys" that you used to store information to check if the product is already bought and then you can set your views accordingly.

If this doesn't serve your purpose, then you might have to start implementing a SQLite database that keeps track of all purchases. Please go through this article on Android Developers as it might help you further:

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/index.html

Hope this helps. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Use [CheckOut library](https://github.com/serso/android-checkout) it does everything for you, you can check for the purchased items and based on the sku you can enable or disable purchase button.